How to integrate startbootstrap into a react component?
I'm working on a React component that incorporates a StartBootstrap template from this link.Here is the full picture of an ideal page:

I organized the css, js, and assets folders inside the public folder to ensure the template renders correctly. Below is how I structured the assets:

I've included the CSS and JS scripts as below into my index.html like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>Dashboard - SB Admin</title>
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/start-bootstrap-assets/css/style.css" />-->



    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@7.1.2/dist/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.3.0/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  <body class="sb-nav-fixed">
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
    <!--<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/start-bootstrap-assets/js/script.js"></script> -->

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/demo/chart-bar-demo.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@7.1.2/dist/umd/simple-datatables.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/datatables-simple-demo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


However, despite my efforts, the HTML page appears broken as below picture:

and i see the following errors related to chart.min.js in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
    at Object.acquireContext (Chart.min.js:7:76631)
    at ni.construct (Chart.min.js:7:92209)
    at new ni (Chart.min.js:7:91964)
    at chart-area-demo.js:7:19

So, i think, still some chart.min.js are not properly addressed in my project.
Can anyone guide me on how to properly set up these assets in my React app to achieve the desired layout?
Link to full code in Github to reproduce this problem!

Update:
As the data of the diagrams and table are not loaded, I think, it is the assets folder which is not propely get loaded into the app.

You put your assets into the public folder. According to the Create-React-App documentation, you need to utilize the public folder with a %PUBLIC_URL% pattern https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/.
For example
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

However, it should be noted, when working with React, that the Bootstrap team recommends you use the React-Bootstrap package instead. And since you are using React, you shouldn't be having Vanilla JavaScript code, as the two may interfere with each other.
I think your system may still work. But if you run into some weird issues, you probably need to spend effort converting the template from Vanilla JS to React.
I also want to say you probably should create and work with your React project using Vite instead of Create-React-App as Vite is generally much faster than Create-React-App and more actively developed

thanks for the advises. I am wondering, if you know any HTML template which is more compatible with React, so that i don't need to convert the vanila js to React ?

I don't know a lot about Bootstrap template, but you can probably google "React bootstrap admin dashboard template". You probably don't want to include "HTML" in your search query, as it usually leads to more vanilla-JS template. Or maybe reconsider if you even need to use React.

first, remove all the cdn links and respective files, then install the package by running:
npm install simple-datatables

after that create a component
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import 'simple-datatables/dist/style.css';
import { DataTable } from 'simple-datatables';

const DataTableComponent = () => {
useEffect(() => {
    // Initialize the DataTable once the component has mounted
    const datatablesSimple = document.getElementById('datatablesSimple');
    if (datatablesSimple) {
        new DataTable(datatablesSimple);
    }
}, []); // Empty dependency array ensures this runs only once when the component mounts
return (
    <div>
        <table id="datatablesSimple">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2012/08/06</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>55</td>
                    <td>2010/10/14</td>
                    <td>$327,900</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>39</td>
                    <td>2009/09/15</td>
                    <td>$205,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>2008/12/13</td>
                    <td>$103,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2008/12/19</td>
                    <td>$90,560</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>36</td>
                    <td>2008/10/16</td>
                    <td>$470,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                    <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>2012/12/18</td>
                    <td>$313,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>2010/03/17</td>
                    <td>$385,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michael Silva</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2012/11/27</td>
                    <td>$198,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                    <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2010/06/09</td>
                    <td>$725,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gloria Little</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2009/04/10</td>
                    <td>$237,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>2012/10/13</td>
                    <td>$132,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dai Rios</td>
                    <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                    <td>2012/09/26</td>
                    <td>$217,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                    <td>Development Lead</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2011/09/03</td>
                    <td>$345,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                    <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                    <td>2009/06/25</td>
                    <td>$675,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                    <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>2011/12/12</td>
                    <td>$106,450</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>2010/09/20</td>
                    <td>$85,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                    <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/10/09</td>
                    <td>$1,200,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>42</td>
                    <td>2010/12/22</td>
                    <td>$92,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>2010/11/14</td>
                    <td>$357,650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>28</td>
                    <td>2011/06/07</td>
                    <td>$206,850</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fiona Green</td>
                    <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>48</td>
                    <td>2010/03/11</td>
                    <td>$850,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shou Itou</td>
                    <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>2011/08/14</td>
                    <td>$163,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michelle House</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>Sidney</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2011/06/02</td>
                    <td>$95,400</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Suki Burks</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>53</td>
                    <td>2009/10/22</td>
                    <td>$114,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                    <td>Technical Author</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/05/07</td>
                    <td>$145,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                    <td>Team Leader</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2008/10/26</td>
                    <td>$235,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                    <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>2011/03/09</td>
                    <td>$324,050</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Unity Butler</td>
                    <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/12/09</td>
                    <td>$85,675</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>2008/12/16</td>
                    <td>$164,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                    <td>Secretary</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                    <td>2010/02/12</td>
                    <td>$109,850</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                    <td>Financial Controller</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>62</td>
                    <td>2009/02/14</td>
                    <td>$452,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                    <td>Office Manager</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2008/12/11</td>
                    <td>$136,200</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                    <td>Director</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>65</td>
                    <td>2008/09/26</td>
                    <td>$645,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2011/02/03</td>
                    <td>$234,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>38</td>
                    <td>2011/05/03</td>
                    <td>$163,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>37</td>
                    <td>2009/08/19</td>
                    <td>$139,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Thor Walton</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2013/08/11</td>
                    <td>$98,540</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                    <td>Support Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2009/07/07</td>
                    <td>$87,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                    <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>64</td>
                    <td>2012/04/09</td>
                    <td>$138,575</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2010/01/04</td>
                    <td>$125,250</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                    <td>Software Engineer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>56</td>
                    <td>2012/06/01</td>
                    <td>$115,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                    <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    <td>2013/02/01</td>
                    <td>$75,650</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>2011/12/06</td>
                    <td>$145,600</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>47</td>
                    <td>2011/03/21</td>
                    <td>$356,250</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lael Greer</td>
                    <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td>2009/02/27</td>
                    <td>$103,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                    <td>Developer</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>2010/07/14</td>
                    <td>$86,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shad Decker</td>
                    <td>Regional Director</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>51</td>
                    <td>2008/11/13</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                    <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Singapore</td>
                    <td>29</td>
                    <td>2011/06/27</td>
                    <td>$183,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna Snider</td>
                    <td>Customer Support</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>27</td>
                    <td>2011/01/25</td>
                    <td>$112,000</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>)
};
export default DataTableComponent;

